# Getting Error in Android manifest file when creating navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am creating an app with a navigation drawer. It is going well I have added my menu file drawer header file. But when I am writing the logic code in MainActivity file I am getting error in Android manifest file at the ".MainActivity" place.

error is "Unresolved class 'MainActivity' "

code:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)

    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_nav, R.string.close_nav)

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragement()).commit()
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_general)
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_general -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragement()).commit()
        R.id.nav_pred -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, MLFragment()).commit()
        R.id.nav_safety -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, SafetyFragment()).commit()
        R.id.nav_about -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, AboutFragment()).commit()
        R.id.nav_logout -> Toast.makeText(this, "Logout!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

}

I tried to delete the file and created another but I am getting the same issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What's your app's "package name". Have you tried adding your package name in your app module level gradle file?

[image: Your package name comes after that 'namespace =' directive]

This namespace used to belong in Manifest file in past but now it needs to be declared in app level build.gradle file.

It tell your app where to look for your classes, so it's the parent directory of sub-level directories(packages).

Answer (score 0):

The error raised due to the path of the package being different. After I have imported the correct package and path the error is gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).